# Origin of the expression 'a tutta birra'

Tags: idioms

What is the origin of the Italian expression 'a tutta birra' meaning 'at full speed'? Is it really related to beer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it probably isn't. I've found that *"a tutta birra"* can be derived from a wrong translation of the French expression *à toute bride*, which should be translated as *"a tutta briglia"*. "Briglia" means **bridle**, so the original expression is used to indicate that someone goes/something is done at full speed, like a galloping horse.

At the moment, I've found very few references about this topic, like [this dictionary](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/B/birra.shtml) or [this blog entry](http://paginedipergamena.blogspot.it/2013/06/perche-si-dice-andare-tutta-birra.html). Nothing academical or proved, I'm sorry.

User @Federico found out an interesting fact. Comparing the frequency of the expressions "a tutta birra" and "a tutta briglia" in Italian books, using Google Ngram Viewer, shows that our beloved "a tutta birra" starts to appear around the '30s of last century.

[image: graph showing the frequency of the two expressions in Italian literature.]

Could it be related to the increasing use of cars which took place in those years? Here, we can just make hypothesis, but the use of this expression has been kept increasing for years, definitively surpassing the original "a tutta briglia" in the 70’s ([here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20tutta%20birra%2Ca%20tutta%20briglia&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20tutta%20birra%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20tutta%20briglia%3B%2Cc0) you can play with Ngram).

**Edit:** 
This interpretation can also be found in the book *Acqua in bocca! Tutto quello che vorresti dire in italiano... come lo direbbe un italiano!* by Roberto Bortoluzzi (Edizioni Casa delle lingue, Barcellona, 2015). This book also mentions that another Italian idiom closely related to the French idiom *à toute bride* (from which probably "a tutta birra" derives) is "a rotta di collo".

**Are there other interpretations?**

User @randomatlabuser enlightened me about another possible interpretation of the expression "a tutta birra". In fact, it seems that in the past horses were given beer as an energy drink, especially before going through hard parts of the travel. Also, modern diets for race horses include brewer's yeast, which is supposed to enhance the performance during the race ([here](http://www.focus.it/cultura/storia/perche-si-dice-a-tutta-birra) it's briefly explained).

Comment: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+tutta+birra%2Ca+tutta+briglia&year_start=1780&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20tutta%20birra%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20tutta%20briglia%3B%2Cc0) seems to support your idea: in particular see how the "birra" starts to be used/found [after 1930](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+tutta+birra%2Ca+tutta+briglia&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20tutta%20birra%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20tutta%20briglia%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I always thought that _a tutta birra_ was the same as _a tutto gas_, i.e., _at full throttle_, where the _birra_ stood for the British _petrol_ or the American _gas_.

Comment: They have the same meaning, in fact.

Comment: Beer is synonym of energy, [read here](http://www.focus.it/cultura/storia/perche-si-dice-a-tutta-birra). Apparently they even use to give beer to horses to improve performance.

Comment: @randomatlabuser - that is interesting too..you could elaborate the issue  into an answer if you want.

Comment: @randomatlabuser I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @uomoinverde, well done!